# How to align two columns of text in CSS

Tags: css, css-position, vertical-alignment

I'm having some trouble lining up some text. I need two columns, one with numbers and one with text, like so:

1 Entry one
2 Entry two
3 Entry three
4 Entry five
5 Entry six

The left column is Georgia and the right column is Arial (slightly different font sizes). I could have a container div for each row and absolutely position the number and text paragraphs to be at the top or bottom of these, which works fine. The problem is this means I have to give each row a fixed height so that it displays properly, which causes a problem if the text needs to flow onto more than one line (which it may well do as the text entries are dynamic).

I want to do this without using a table, and without using absolute positioning so that the individual text entries can span over more than one line (and is cross-browser compatible).

Comment: Why don't you want to use a table for this?

Comment: any reason you're not using an `<ol>` for this, do the numbers need their own element?

Comment: @AllisonC Because this is an ordered list, not a table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my comment, I think the best element for the job is an [ordered list](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#edef-OL).

```css
ol {
   font-family: georgia, serif;
   font-size: 16px;
   font-weight: bold;
}
ol li span {
   font-family: arial, sans-serif;
   font-weight: normal;
   font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li><span>Entry one<br>text on another line</span></li>
  <li><span>Entry two</span></li>
  <li><span>Entry three</span></li>
  <li><span>Entry five</span></li>
  <li><span>Entry six</span></li>
</ol>
```

With the span to allow changing of `font-family` between the list "bullets" and the content within, these could be divs if you have block content.

Comment: Doh! I'm not sure how I missed that, of course it's an ordered list, that works perfectly :) Out of interest if I want the bullets/numbers inline but i don't want the text to flow under them is the correct way to use padding-left: 1.5em; list-style-position: outside; or is there a cleaner way? Additionally is there any cross browser way of removing the fullstop after each number? Thanks so much for your help, it is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: @deshg: Regarding `"is there any cross browser way of removing the fullstop after each number"` - which browsers do you need to support?

Comment: @thirtydot: As many browsers as is possible, ideally all but I appreciate that's a big ask for most things these days!!

Comment: @thirtydot and @clairesuzy, i have just realised that using the above code the line spacing of the text is very large if the text for one bullet runs over 2 or more lines (i presume 17px to match the ol?). Is there any way to decrese the line spacing for just the text as it has no effect when i set it on the span and if i set it on the li then there is much more spacing in firefox than any other browser (which is unusual). I'd be very grateful if you had any ideas why this might be? Thanks so much

Answer (score 3):

You should just use an appropriately styled `ol` element, something like this:

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/tPjQR/

If you want to have different styles on the number versus the list content, you'll need to wrap the content of each `li` in something like a `span`. There just isn't a better way.

```
ol {
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
}
ol span {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px
}
<ol>
    <li><span>Entry one</span></li>
    <li><span>Entry two</span></li>
    <li><span>Entry three</span></li>
    <li><span>Entry five</span></li>
    <li><span>Entry six</span></li>
    <li><span>Entry Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long</span></li>
</ol>
```