# How to line up each word in a list so that entries start at the same point horizontally?

Tags: html, css, alignment

Here's an example I've changed slightly from a [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112609/how-to-align-two-columns-of-text-in-css):
http://jsfiddle.net/tPjQR/72/

```css
ol {
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
}
ol span {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li><span>Entry one</span></li>
    <li><span>Entry two</span></li>
    <li><span>Entrye three</span></li>
    <li><span>Entry five</span></li>
    <li><span>Entry six</span></li>
    <li><span>Entry Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long</span></li>
</ol>
```

I would like to line up the columns so that, no matter how much text is in one column, the first characters of each column will be lined up.

E.g.

***not***

```
Entry one
Entry two
Entrye three
Entry five
Entry six
```

***rather***

```
Entry  one
Entry  two
Entrye three
Entry  five
Entry  six
```

Is there a way to do this with list items, or do I need to use a table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the below code to get that design...

```css
li span {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li><span>Entry</span> one</li>
    <li><span>Entry</span> two</li>
    <li><span>Entrye</span> three</li>
    <li><span>Entry</span> five</li>
    <li><span>Entry</span> six</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: If you wanted to use a percentage for width (with a certain number of columns, say 4), could you just write width: 25%?

Comment: you can also use table if you need

Answer (score 3):

An alternative method...

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

ol li:before {
  content: "Entry";
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>five</li>
  <li>six</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can change your `css`

```
li span {
    display:inline-block;
    width:15%;

}

li  p {text-align: left; display:inline-block; margin : 0px 45px;}
```

`inline-block` **value of the display property makes this even easier**

**CSS** `margin` **properties are used to generate space around elements.**
learn more about that [CSS Margins](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp)

```css
li span {
    display:inline-block;  width:15%;

}
li  p {text-align: left; display:inline-block; margin : 0px 75px;}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li><span>Entry </span> <p>
    
  one</p></li>
   <li><span>Entry</span> <p>
    
  two</p></li>
  <li><span>Entryre</span> <p>
    
    three</p></li>
  <li><span>Entry</span> <p>
    
    fiv</p></li>
   <li><span>Entry</span> <p>
    
    six</p></li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually code as the following:

```css
.list01 {
  width: 200px;
}
.list01 li {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.col01 {
  float: left;
  width: 5em;
}
.col02 {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<ol class="list01">
  <li><span class="col01">Entry</span><span class="col02">long long long one</span></li>
  <li><span class="col01">Entry</span><span class="col02">two</span></li>
  <li><span class="col01">Entrye</span><span class="col02">three</span></li>
  <li><span class="col01">Entry</span><span class="col02">five</span></li>
  <li><span class="col01">Entry</span><span class="col02">six</span></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: its no t a correct align , please check it or im wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not possible beacuse the DOM object rendering is based on its architructure and what you want to do is possible through the tables.

```css
* {
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td>Entry</td><td>One</td></tr>
<tr><td>Entry</td><td>Two</td></tr>
<tr><td>Entry Xyz</td><td>Three</td></tr>
<tr><td>Entry</td><td>Four</td></tr>
<tr><td>Entry</td><td>Five</td></tr>
<tr><td>Entry</td><td>Six</td></tr>
</table>
```